# Ubuntu 16.04 internal Error, Xorg crash

Tags: 16.04, xorg, crash, error-handling

my OS reports about this internal crash every time I start my computer,

How do I find its log file and about this problem

[Internal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZXKt.png)

[Internal error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fEm7.png)

Comment: It says video service crash. Keep in mind in a few weeks 16.04 loses all support as it will be aged out. So maybe time for an upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want the Xorg log files:

```
ls -ltr /var/log/Xorg.0.*
```